# Trying to load images from firebase separately from the rest of the data in a tableview

Tags: swift, image, firebase, uitableview

I have a tableview with a bunch of cells populated from Firebase Real-time (for text), and Firebase Storage (for images).  The code I have put together waits for all the text and images to download, before presenting the table.

I'd ideally like the text to load first into the cells, followed by the relevant images.

The code setup is as follows:

1. Main viewcontroller
2. Tableviewcell file that stores the label and image view.
3. A model file.

The main function that's giving me the problem is as follows:

```
    func LoadDataFromImageTest() {


    databaseReference = Database.database().reference()

    let refPVV = Database.database().reference(withPath: "PVV").queryOrdered(byChild: "Status").queryEqual(toValue: "Active")

    refPVV.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in

        //if the reference have some values
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

            //clearing the list
            self?.FBImageList.removeAll()

            //iterating through all the values
            for PVV in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                //getting values
                let PVVObject = PVV.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let PVVImageName  = PVVObject?["ImageName"] as! String?
                let PVVName = PVVObject?["Name"] as! String?

                let imageURL = Storage.storage().reference().child(PVVImageName!)

                imageURL.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

                    if error != nil {
                        print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                        return
                    }

                    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                        if error != nil {
                            print(error as Any)
                            return
                        }

                        guard let imageData = UIImage(data: data!) else { return }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {



                            let PVV = FBImageModel(ImageName: imageData as UIImage?, Name: PVVName as String?)
                            self!.FBImageList.insert(PVV, at: 0)

                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            //reloading the tableview
                            self?.FBImageTableView.reloadData()
                        }

                    }).resume()
                })
            }
        }
    }
)}
```

How must this be changed in order to get the images to load individually after the text label is populated for all the cells?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

Comment: How would I do that in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using FirebaseUI . install FirebaseUI Pod

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage'
```

Then use below code

```
 // Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
    let reference = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg")


    // Placeholder image
    let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")

    // Load the image in your imageView using SDWebImage
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

In your scenario, dont download the imageData. just change your image Model to store the Storage reference and while creating the rows, use `sd_setImage` method to populate the image

Comment: Ajay, where would I do what you suggested?

1.  In the function I quoted above?
2.  In the tableviewcell file?
3.  In the tableview cellForRowAt function?

Comment: you can set the reference to the FBImageList in function quoted above. and in cellForRow at function use the sd_setimage method with the reference

Comment: or you can create the reference directly in the cellForRowAtIndexpath using the imageName
 let imageURL = Storage.storage().reference().child(PVVImageName!).

Comment: Ajay, thanks for the hints.  I got it working with your help!  I grabbed the URL first, added it to the model in the main function.  the cellForRowAtIndexpath function then takes the URL, which is then used by sd_setImage.

Comment: Your welcome @nm1213 . if its help you, then the answer may deserve a thumbs up

Comment: and select the answer so others may find it as working solution